# jQuery - braces of a POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the following code for a jQuery [POST](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) request. I don't understand the braces, isn't it closed already before the .done function is called?

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
 alert( "success" );
})
 .done(function() {
   alert( "second success" );
 })
 .fail(function() {
   alert( "error" );
 })
 .always(function() {
   alert( "finished" );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done, but it returns a jqXHR object, to which you can still apply functions, e.g.: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Answer (score 2):

`$.post` is a function, which is stored in a property (`post`) of an object stored in the `$` variable.

`$.post()` calls that function and returns a return value (in this case, a jqXHR object).

`$.post().done` is another function, which is stored in a property (`done`) of the value returned from calling `$.post()`.

Comment: And it's called 'method chaining' - http://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html

Answer (score 1):

It's called chaining.

`"something".length.toString().length.toString();`

Each method is called on the result of the previous method.

Comment: That example throws errors. `length` is not a function.

Comment: I can nevar remebmer, is length a function, or just a property :D

Comment: `"something".length.toString().length.toString();` length is a property i think

Comment: @MārtiņšBriedis: Generally, a property is used when it returns a value that is already known or trivial to calculate, while a method is used when a new object or value is created or some processing is done. So `length` is a property because the value is already known, while `toString` is a method because it creates a new string instance. :)

Comment: @Guffa I blame Java for my confusion, because `length` is a method there.

Comment: @MārtiņšBriedis: The use of properties of course only applies to languages that actually have properties... :)